# Defining a DataTemplateBase

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have defined some `DataTemplates` are similar. The templates are like this:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultCellTemplate">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <beh:AddErrorButtonAdornerToControlsBehavior 
                DoOnButtonClick="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type dxg:GridControl}}, Path=DataContext.ShowErrorDialogCommand}" 
                FieldDescriptionId="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type dxg:GridCellContentPresenter}}, Path=Column.Tag}"/>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="TimeCellTemplate">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value, Converter={StaticResource TimeConverter}}">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <beh:AddErrorButtonAdornerToControlsBehavior 
                DoOnButtonClick="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type dxg:GridControl}}, Path=DataContext.ShowErrorDialogCommand}" 
                FieldDescriptionId="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type dxg:GridCellContentPresenter}}, Path=Column.Tag}"/>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="StationCellTemplate">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value, Converter={StaticResource StationConverter}}">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <beh:AddErrorButtonAdornerToControlsBehavior 
                DoOnButtonClick="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type dxg:GridControl}}, Path=DataContext.ShowErrorDialogCommand}" 
                FieldDescriptionId="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type dxg:GridCellContentPresenter}}, Path=Column.Tag}"/>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="ProductionCategoryCellTemplate">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value, Converter={StaticResource ProductionCategoryConverter}}">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <beh:AddErrorButtonAdornerToControlsBehavior 
                DoOnButtonClick="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type dxg:GridControl}}, Path=DataContext.ShowErrorDialogCommand}" 
                FieldDescriptionId="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type dxg:GridCellContentPresenter}}, Path=Column.Tag}"/>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```

I don't know, if I can define a template base. The template base should be a `TextBlock` with the behavior and the derived templates should be use a converter for the `TextBlock` value. Any idea?

Comment: Is there any difference expected between the data templates?

Answer (score 2):

Real inheritance is not possible in `DataTemplate` through XAML, as far as I know. What you can do with is use a nested construction of `DataTemplate`s.

The method boils down to using a `ContentPresenter` and setting the `ContentTemplate` property in order to achieve your nesting.

Solutions are already presented on SO and Google; both give a good bit of information:

- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918132/in-wpf-can-you-base-one-datatemplate-on-another-like-you-can-with-a-style)
- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443600/is-there-a-way-to-use-data-template-inheritance-in-wpf)
- [Google](http://dariosantarelli.wordpress.com/2011/07/28/wpf-inheritance-and-datatemplates/)